# IntelliJ (Git) - cleared stash and recovered it

Tags: git, intellij-idea

IDE : IntelliJ
I just clicked on the "clear" in the unstash window by mistake **and lost a huge stash.**
Is there any way to get them back?

(Why is the question getting voted down when none of the solutions that people suggested helped me to recover from my problem. Is one suppose to ask only pedantic and pedagogical questions? )

Comment: there are about 5 levels of stage/stash/commit/indexing things in git. however clearing the stash does not go into any of them. your work is lost.

Comment: Did "gitk --all ." show the stash commit still?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I lost the stash. But since I was using IntelliJ all through for coding, it kept local history of all the file for almost 1 week.

How I recovered my files using IntelliJ?
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/viewing-local-history-of-a-file-or-folder.html#

After that I created a patch (right click on file and time when you thought your changes were stashed) and carefully selected only those files that were modified by me.

Now apply the patch and you are good to go.

Comment: My work was too old to show up in local history, but this was still helpful.